# Set value of persistence.xml file with properties.config file

Tags: java, eclipse, persistence, persistence.xml

I want to set the values of my persistence.xml file with the values from my properties.config.

Is there any way to do this? Like any buildin function?

I think to a function like

```
factory.setvaluesfrompersistence(config.getpropertie("name"));
```

I want to do this bc I don't want to set my personal values in the persistence.xml so if I deploy this version there is no sesible data in there.

I use EclipseLink as JPA Propvider

my properties.config:

```
db.url=
db.user=
db.psw=
```

and my persistens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="test"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>my.test.test</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How I call it:

```
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        final EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        final Query q = em.createQuery("select b from Beruf b");
        final List<Beruf> BerufeList = q.getResultList();
        for (final Beruf beruf : BerufeList) {
            System.out.println(beruf);
        }

        em.close();
```

Comment: Are you using a framework like Spring or deploying your application in an application server?

Comment: I use Maven in Eclipse.

Comment: So how are you bootstrapping EclipseLink then? Can you hook into that process, especially creation of the entity manager factory? If so, did you try passing the properties to the constructor/factory method? Besides that, did you try passing `javax.persistence.jdbc.user` directly from the command line?

Comment: I am not sure what you want :/. I added EclipseLink over Maven in my Eclipse. And all I want is to pass the User and Password in my Code to the entity manager factory. 
Like i create a variable "db.user" = "test"; and then I just want to pass it to a func like factory.createEnityManager(db.user) or sth like this (beste case Build in). And it should "set" the values like if  I write it in the persistence.xml. 

If I hard code it in my persiscene.xml it works like a charm and I get the values from my DB.

Comment: EclipseLink doesn't "automagically" start up if you have it as a dependency (at least not to my knowledge) so there needs to be some code that actually tells EclipseLink to start, create the factory etc. Where does `factory` in your code come from?

Comment: "private static EntityManagerFactory factory;" in my class constructor

Comment: Well, and how is that field initialized? Where does the value come from? Please don't just post small snippets but provide a [mcve]. Read through the comments above and post relevant code. I'll try to recap them again: we need to see how you are initializing EclipseLink, where and how the factories are created etc. - if there's no such code in your application then you're likely using some framework and in that case we need to know which one. Without that information it's hard to help - this would amount to "it hurts" without telling us where.

Comment: my Main calls :            ` final BerufeEinlesenWorkflow bew = new BerufeEinlesenWorkflow(config);
            bew.run();`
Config is my properties.config.
and my class BerufeEinlesenWorkflow:

Comment: My class has the cunstructor: 
public class BerufeEinlesenWorkflow {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BerufeEinlesenWorkflow.class);
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "berufe";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private final CSV_Reader myReader = new CSV_Reader();
    private final PropertyManager config;
    public BerufeEinlesenWorkflow(PropertyManager config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

Comment: and there is the func run() with the code: 

public void run() throws IOException { final List<Beruf> berufe = myReader.fileRead(config.getProperty("input.file")); for (final Beruf b : berufe) { // System.out.println(b); } logger.info("Wrote CSV-file correct"); factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME); final EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager(); final Query q = em.createQuery("select b from Beruf b"); final List<Beruf> BerufeList = q.getResultList(); for (final Beruf beruf : BerufeList) { System.out.println(beruf); } em.close(

Comment: I'm not going to read that code in the comments as the formatting is horrible. Rather than providing additional information that's asked for in comments, go and [edit] your question and add it there (nicely formatted of course). You might also want to read [ask] for good measure.

Comment: Finally, as I already suspected, you should be able to pass the properties when creating the persistence unit. Have a look at [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String,Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-), read the properties you need from whatever location you want, put the values into the map and use keys as required by `persistence.xml` (the property names), and pass the map to that method.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Big ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Is to create a Map where you set the key from persistence.xml file and give it a new value.